# R interacting with c++ by means of Rcpp to solve large ODE systems

Tags: c++, r, boost, rcpp

I'm trying to speedup my R code performing some computationally expensive task with C++ and Rcpp. My problem involves approximately a system of 100 equations, so any hint to speed up the computation is welcome.

What I need is to import a matrix *MX* created in R into a C++ script. The C++ script have to use rows of *MX* as *x0* (*x* initial values) in a systems of ODE.

To simplify the explanation of my problem, the code below is based on the Lorenz systems.

As it is clear from the quality of my code, I'm new to C++ (and Rcpp).

For clarity, I don't post all my test code that are terrible, bu I really need your help to try solve this problem.

Any help will be really, really appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

double theta [] = {10.000,28,2.5};

typedef boost::array< double , 3 > state_type;

void lorenz( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , double t ) {
    dxdt[0] = theta[0] * ( x[1] - x[0] );
    dxdt[1] = theta[1] * x[0] - x[1] - x[0] * x[2];
    dxdt[2] = -theta[2] * x[2] + x[0] * x[1];
}


struct foo { std::vector<double> a, b, c; };
struct foo f;

//observer should be a function that append a single output row for each input row of mx corresponding to the last integration step. 

void append_lorenz(const state_type &x , const double t ) {
    f.a.push_back(x[0]);
    f.b.push_back(x[1]);
    f.c.push_back(x[2]);
}

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

DataFrame callMain(NumericMatrix mx){
    int n = mx.nrow();
    NumericMatrix total(mx);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
// state_type x should be mx rows
            state_type x = total.row(i); // initial conditions
            const double dt =0.1;
            integrate(lorenz , x , 0.0 , 1.0 , dt , append_lorenz );

    }
    return DataFrame::create(Named("a") = f.a, Named("b") = f.b,  Named("c") = f.c);

}

/*** R
mx=matrix(1:9,3,3)
res <- callMain(mx)
print((res))
*/
```

the error I get is:
error: conversion from ‘Rcpp::Matrix<14>::Row {aka Rcpp::MatrixRow<14>}’ to non-scalar type ‘state_type {aka boost::array}’ requested
    state_type x = total.row(i); // initial conditions

Comment: _"Hello, world! Please fix my code."_ questions are likely to get shut down here.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: you have to state your problem. It doesn't compile? Doesn't link? REsult is different from expected?

Comment: You question is too broad. One thing I see right away is that you are passing the matrix `mx` by value, which results in copying. This is bad when large matrices are used. Use pass by reference (`NumericMatrix &mx`). Also, you are making another copy (`total`) of that matrix. Use `mx` directly, do not copy it.

Comment: @Marko: _psasing the matrix `mx` by value, which results in copying_: Nope, these are proxy objects in Rcpp. Only a pointer and some metadata gets copied.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my bad quality question. I agree with you, I have to be more specific. I'll edit my question focusing on a single problem, hoping this coulb be specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is clear enough.

```
state_type x = total.row(i);
```

There is no conversion between Rcpp object and `boost::array`, you need to develop your own.